# Link error: Installing boost zlib filters using NuGet in Visual Studio (2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, nuget, zlib

I've installed these packages:

- boost
- boost-vc110
- boost_iostreams_zlib
- zlib

But the linker is unable to find the required lib:

`2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_zlib-vc110-mt-1_58.lib'`

Is there a way to fix this problem manually by changing the file name or am I still missing a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.

I just had to add `BOOST_IOSTREAMS_NO_LIB` to the Preprocessor definitions in the C/C++ tab.